# Sharepoint search api - Search through all sites and retrieve all documents

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

[image]

I am trying to build a spfx web part that will search through all the sites in my tennacy and return all the documents appearing in all document libraryslists.

Does anybody have a search api end point I can use to do this?

```
https://hiddenforsecurity.sharepoint.com/sites/KIM/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList2')/items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,EncodedAbsUrl"
```

The above endpoint is only searching one site. Help please <3

Is their a website/tool that can help me build the endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Sharepoint REST api, to scope only a site use : Path managedProperty
use then managed property ContentType on ContentTypeId:0x0101*

```
http://llu-sp2016-dev:34436/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:Document Path:http://llu-sp2016-dev:34436*'&selectproperties='Title,Path,ParentLink,SiteName,ContentType'&RowLimit=120
```

an exemple available on : [query search with rest](http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/blog/sharepointquerysearchwithrest.html)